# Azure Git Continuous Deploy for node not working

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-git-deployment

We have a REST API (npm restify) to deploy to Azure and it was successful.

After this we have the web.config pointing it to the app.js in the root (was server.js as stock). Looking at the logs it says pointing to 0.0.0.0 on port 8085. We are not sure how to change this as we have env variables set to change these but Azure kudu doesnt seem to listen.

The app.js is also just a module.exports = require(".src/server.js"); Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the env variables. We had BLAH_BLAH_PORT when it should have been just PORT

Comment: We won't ask why you had `BLAH_BLAH_PORT` in there :)

Comment: @DavidEbbo was the name of the app ;) haha